# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile targetSdk deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I set up my `build.gradle.kts` file in the `shared` module of my KMM project like the following snippets shows:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.my.project"
    compileSdk = 33

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
    }
}
```

For the `targetSDK` I get the following warning:

```
targetSdk: Int?' is deprecated. Will be removed from library DSL in v9.0
```

How can I migrate this part and set the `targetSdk` version appropriately in my KMM project for the Android project?

Comment: To migrate the targetSdk version in your KMM project, you can update your build.gradle.kts file to use the targetSdkVersion property instead of targetSdk.

Comment: The `targetSdkVersion` property is also deprecated.

Comment: You can remove that, not required for sub-modules. Just keep at application level Gradle and that is still the same.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `targetSdk` property in the Android **library** Gradle plugin (`"com.android.library"`) has been deprecated. As it is an advisory property, you can safely remove it from your configuration. The `minSdk` property alone is sufficient. Refer to the [LibraryBaseFlavor reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/LibraryBaseFlavor#targetSdk()) for the deprecation message.

**Note:** Do not confuse this with the Android **application** Gradle plugin (`"com.android.application"`). In that case, the `targetSdk` property remains essential and has not been deprecated.